# Pushing Bigquery data to Google sheets using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

MY script pulls data from Bigquery and saves it in google sheets but every time my script is triggered the sheet gets cleared and values are updated from the start date to the end date

Is there a possibility to append and only update few days of data where there is a data discrepancy rather than clearing and updating the whole sheet?

```
my script :

/**
* Runs a BigQuery query and logs the results in a spreadsheet.
*/
function runQuery() {
// Replace this value with the project ID listed in the Google
// Cloud Platform project.
var projectId = 'xxxxx';

var request = {
query: 'SELECT date, month, channel_grouping, device_category ' +
'FROM `xxxxx` where date between "2020-01-01" and "2020-01-03" order by date ;',
useLegacySql : false
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;

// Check on status of the Query Job.
var sleepTimeMs = 500;
while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
sleepTimeMs *= 2;
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
}

// Get all the rows of results.
var rows = queryResults.rows;
while (queryResults.pageToken) {
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {
pageToken: queryResults.pageToken
});
rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
}

if (rows) {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yOhjzprF2FXt3dM-FktVyVWNW1fCBhRO63f-QK-y3CQ');
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clear();

// Append the headers.
var headers = queryResults.schema.fields.map(function(field) {
return field.name;
});
sheet.appendRow(headers);

// Append the results.
var data = new Array(rows.length);
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
var cols = rows[i].f;
data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
}
}
sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, cols.length).setValues(data);

Logger.log('Results spreadsheet created: %s',
spreadsheet.getUrl());
} else {
Logger.log('No rows returned.');
}
}
```

Comment: Change the 2 in "sheet.getRange(2" into: sheet.getLastRow()+1

Comment: How often do you need to upload the data? And what date ranges are you willing to check? I guess the dates should be dynamic (e.g. upload only the last 3 days of data)

Comment: in that case you need to remove the `clear()` method, not `appendRow()` headers and make `getRange()` start at `sheet.getLastRow() + 1` instead of `2`